# Add a shadow around a UIImageView's UIImage that has clear pixels

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, calayer

I would like to add a shadow around my `UIImage` (not the image view)

Adding shadow to the `UIImageViews` layer would be rectangular because its frame is so this isn't a good solution...

Is there a way to add the shadow to the edge of the image - hugging its contour, disregarding the clear pixles?